# SpringBoot Initalisation

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have written a SpringBoot application and the sequence in which the initial log statements execute in my machine's console is different than in my teammate's machine.

## Log Snapshot:

SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.

**Line X-** SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/Users/d0p00no/Documents/workspace-sts-3.9.4.RELEASE/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/RxOnlineServices/WEB-INF/lib/logback-classic-1.2.3.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]

**Line Y-**  SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/Users/d0p00no/Documents/workspace-sts-3.9.4.RELEASE/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/RxOnlineServices/WEB-INF/lib/strati-af-logging-log4j2-slf4j-impl-4.3.2.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]

Here the lines X and Y were interchanged in the other system.

So I wonder whether multiple threads are used while loading the SpringBoot application?

Tech Stack: Maven, External Tomcat 8.05, Hibernate

Comment: Hello. Welcome to SO. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @MickaëlB I have updated the question.